# Replacing values and converting to numeric using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data (it's messy, I know, but bear with me):

```
a <- c("Table Title", rep(NA, 10))
b <- c("Characteristic", "Year 1", "", "Year 2", "", "Year 3", "", "Year 4", "", "Year 5", "")
c <- c("All", "40", "%", "20", "%", "12", "%", "43", "%", "8", "%")
e <- c("Male", "22", "%", "14", "%", "8", "%", "39", "%", "4", "%")

df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,e), stringsAsFactors = F)
setDT(df)

df

               X1     X2   X3     X4   X5     X6   X7     X8   X9    X10  X11
1:    Table Title   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>
2: Characteristic Year 1      Year 2      Year 3      Year 4      Year 5     
3:            All     40    %     20    %     12    %     43    %      8    %
4:           Male     22    %     14    %      8    %     39    %      4    %
```

I would like to do two things: (1) Strip "Year " from the second row, and (2) convert the even columns to numeric.

For the first step, I tried:

```
df[2] #gives me entire second row
length(df[2]) #11
gsub("Year ", "", df[2]) #Gives me desired output 
length(gsub("Year ", "", df[2])) #11

(df[2] <- gsub("Year ", "", df[2])) #Error

Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2, value = c("Characteristic", "1",  : 
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'X1'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

I don't understand why it's telling me there is a discrepancy when both items have length 11. I then tried:

```
df[2] <- lapply(df[2], gsub, pattern = "Year ", replacement = "") #Works
```

This worked, and gave me the desired output

```
               X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10  X11
1:    Table Title <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2: Characteristic    1         2         3         4         5     
3:            All   40    %   20    %   12    %   43    %    8    %
4:           Male   22    %   14    %    8    %   39    %    4    %
```

although to be honest I'm not sure I fully understand why.

For the second step, I haven't been able to figure out a solution. I've tried a couple different things based on responses to other questions here, but each time I receive an error message.

```
(i <- grep("[0-9]", df[2])) #Index of desired columns

df[,i] <- as.numeric(df[,i]) #Doesn't work for data.table, as stated in documentation

df[,..i] #Selects proper columns
sapply(df[,..i], as.numeric) #Converts columns to numeric
df[,..i] <- sapply(df[,..i], as.numeric) #Object '..i' not found

Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , ..i, value = c(NA, 1, 40, 22, NA,  : 
  object '..i' not found


df[, .SD, .SDcols = i] #Selects proper columns
sapply(df[, .SD, .SDcols = i], as.numeric) #Converts to numeric

df[, .SD, .SDcols = i] <- sapply(df[, .SD, .SDcols = i], as.numeric) #unused argument (.SDcols = i)

Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , .SD, .SDcols = i, value = c(NA, 1,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = i)


df[, .SDcols=..i, ..i := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), ] #object '..i' not found

Error in eval(colsub, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : 
  object '..i' not found
```

I tried different variations of these three attempts, but with the same error messages each time. I suspect the first step above is related to this second step somehow, though I can't say for sure.

What am I missing here?

Comment: first part: `df[ 2, names(df) := lapply( .SD, function(x) gsub( "Year", "", x) ) ]`

Comment: The first row should have been skipped during data import. The second row should be column headers. Then you would melt to long format as a first step.

Comment: @Roland I agree under normal circumstances, but in this case I've just been asked to make minor modifications (e.g. round some numbers and edit the characteristic labels in the first column) without the need for analyses -- and without changing the overall formatting of the tables. I'm certain there's an easier way to do this in a different programming language, but I don't have time (at the moment) to learn alternatives, so I'm sticking with R -- for now. (Although maybe there's an easier way in R that I don't know about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lapply` for `gsub` since you want to change only second row. Also if you use `type.convert` to change column classes you don't need to worry about odd/even columns.

```
library(data.table)

df[2, names(df) := as.list(gsub('Year ', '', df[2]))]
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly -- thanks! 

I am wondering if you (or anyone, really) can point me in the direction of an explanation as to why I was receiving the above error messages, though. I'd like to understand what the problem was in case I run into a similar issue in the future. 

Also, if I have a vector of numbers corresponding to column positions (as I did above with 'i'), is the `..i` notation correct? How would I use it in this case? Just trying to learn as I go.